# DataTables not found in Angular Datatables using Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I've been upgrading a Symfony application from `3.4` to `4.2.2`, everything is fine but I cannot get DataTables to function via yarn install and webpack encore with [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome).

### How I've set it up

**Yarn install**:

```
yarn add jquery@2.1.4
yarn add angular@1.4.8
yarn add datatables.net@1.10.19
yarn add datatables.net-dt@1.10.11
yarn add angular-datatables@0.6.2
```

Added those files to my Webpack `app.js` along with jQuery:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('datatables.net');
require('datatables.net-dt');
require('angular');
require('angular-datatables');
```

Included the `app.js` inside of my Webpack config file:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

and included the above in my front-end template via:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

### The Error

The above results in the following Javascript error which seems to show the DataTables API is not accessible.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Api' of undefined
at initAngularDataTables (angular-datatables.js:478)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4523)
```

```
/* @ngInject */
function initAngularDataTables() {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.Api) {
        /**
         * Register an API to destroy a DataTable without detaching the tbody so that we can add new data
         * when rendering with the "Angular way".
         */
        $.fn.DataTable.Api.register('ngDestroy()', function(remove) {
            remove = remove || false;
```

---

### Possible Solution

I've tried the following hacky fix but it means I have to have my Angular code in the same app.js file else it doesn't work. It also means some functions still fail...

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('jquery-ui');
require('bootstrap');
require('admin-lte');
require('datatables.net-dt');
global.moment = require('moment');

$.fn.dataTable = $.fn.DataTable = global.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
```

**Error**:

```
TypeError: _oTable.ngDestroy is not a function
    at _destroyAndCompile (angular-datatables.js:947)
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer I posted?

Answer (score 2):

Your project has `datatables.net` and `datatables.net-dt` as dependency, and both of them has their own dependency `(jQuery>1.7)`. If you don't specify a jQuery version for your project, your dependency tree end up with the latest version of jQuery which is also used by your dependencies.

```
├─jquery@3.3.1
├─datatables.net@1.10.19
└─datatables.net-dt@1.10.11
```

But if you specify an old version of jQuery, your dependency tree end up fetching the latest version of jQuery for your dependencies (yarn does it, npm does not, I don't know why).

```
├─jquery@2.1.4
├─datatables.net@1.10.19
│      └─jquery@3.3.1
└─datatables.net-dt@1.10.11
       └─jquery@3.3.1
```

As a result, you have 2 different jQuery in your porject.

```
const jQuery = require('jquery')
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery) // logs 2.1.4
const DataTable = require('datatables.net')
console.log(DataTable.$.fn.jquery) // logs 3.3.1
```

As DataTable binds itself to an encapsulated instance of jQuery, `jQuery.fn.dataTable` is
obviously `undefined`. To fix this issue, just use the latest version of jQuery in your
project. Or you can recommend yarn to use a fixed version of jQuery for all of it's dependencies adding a resolution directive to your `package.json` file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.8",
    "angular-datatables": "0.6.2",
    "datatables.net": "1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
},
"resolutions": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
}
```

Then execute `yarn install` command, and your unwanted jQuery installations will be taken care of.